# simple_form_for rails radio button inline

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I am trying to get my buttons to display inline and also have a default value because it can't be blank. I am usingplataformatex/simple_form and bootstrap.

```
= f.collection_radio_buttons :is_private, [[true, 'Private'], [false, 'Public']], :first, :last, style: "display:inline", default: true
```

It is rendering this:

```
<span>
  <input id="workout_is_private_true" name="workout[is_private]" type="radio" value="true" />
  <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="workout_is_private_true">Private</label>    
</span>
<span>
  <input id="workout_is_private_false" name="workout[is_private]" type="radio" value="false" />
  <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="workout_is_private_false">Public</label>
</span>
```

It is clear that the `style:` is not working properly but I am not sure what will work.

Following another suggestion I added

```
.radio_buttons { display:inline; }

= f.collection_radio_buttons :is_private, [[true, 'Private'], [false, 'Public']], :first, :last, :item_wrapper_class => 'radio_buttons', :default => true
```

And got:

```
<span class="radio_buttons">
  <input id="workout_is_private_true" name="workout[is_private]" type="radio" value="true" />
  <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="workout_is_private_true">Private</label>
</span>
<span class="radio_buttons">
  <input id="workout_is_private_false" name="workout[is_private]" type="radio" value="false" />
  <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="workout_is_private_false">Public</label>
</span>
```

Just another note that the default value still is not working.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If you want them inline, you need to give the labels the inline class by doing: `:item_wrapper_class => 'inline'`

Here is an example using your code:

```
= f.input :is_private, 
          :collection => [[true, 'Private'], [false, 'Public']], 
          :label_method => :last, 
          :value_method => :first,
          :as => :radio_buttons, 
          :item_wrapper_class => 'inline',
          :checked => true
```

**EDIT:** I just realized that my answer was more specific to simple_form + bootstrap, since bootstrap already has styles defined when giving the label's the inline class. You should be able to use my example though, it will just take some more work on your end in creating your custom css.

Comment: @trev9065 I added an example to my answer using your code, can you try that and see if it works?

Comment: thanks that worked! Any chance you know how to have one of them selected by default?

Comment: if you do :checked => true, then when you update it'll always be true, even if it's set as false

Comment: @Said I'm not sure how it can be done within the available options of simple_form, but a simple ternary check for nil on the attribute will work: `:checked => (@object.is_private.nil? ? true : @object.is_private)`. The `true` is the default value given if `@object` has a nil value for the `is_private` attribute, else use the value of the attribute directly.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out `item_wrapper_class` - didn't see anything in the README but exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
f.collection_radio_buttons :options, [[true, 'Yes'] ,[false, 'No']], :first, :last ,:style =>"display:inline", :default => true
```

Not so sure which gem you use for simple form , but This is the source or a reference on which you can try

```
collection_radio_buttons(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

Comment: I tried it with `:style =>"display:inline", :default => true` but that did not work. I also tried `:html_options => { :style => "display:inline" }` with no result. It is not even displaying in the source.

Comment: I am getting the same issue trev9065. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Using Simple Form with Bootstrap 3 you can use the `radio` class along with the `item_wrapper_class` and `item_wrapper_tag` options.

```
= f.collection_radio_buttons :sort, [[foo,bar],[foo,bar],
  :first, :last,
  item_wrapper_class: :radio,
  item_wrapper_tag: :div
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answer might have not worked because I'm not using Bootstrap.  But there are other ways. I slapped a div with class="radio-buttons" around the buttons and label manually. Then I added this to my style sheet (SASS):

```
.radio-buttons {
  margin: .5em 0;
  span input {
    float: left;
    margin-right: .25em;
    margin-top: -.25em;
  }
  #this grabs the MAIN label only for my radio buttons 
  #since the data type for the table column is string--yours may be different
  label.string { 
    margin-bottom: .5em !important;
  }

  clear: both;
}

.form-block {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: .5em;
}

 .radio-buttons span {
  clear: both;
  display:block;
 }
```

This will make the radio buttons inline on ALL frameworks, though this is tweaked to look the best for Zurb Foundation. ;)

Answer (score 0):

## A simple solution:

**Add a class to the item wrapper**. This class can be whatever you choose. I'm using 'inline' in the example below:

```
form.input :my_field, as: 'radio_buttons' wrapper_html: {class: 'inline'}
```

**Then define some CSS** which only applies to radio button groups (and only the actual radio buttons, not the item label):

```
input.radio_buttons.inline label.radio{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here's an example of what this yields:

[image: The above yields this result]

Comment: Maybe it got removed, but using `as: 'radio'` gives me a `No input found for radio` error.

Comment: Ah, I believe it's "radio_buttons". Updated my answer, let us know if that works. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Just for someone who using zurb foundation with simple form's chekbox came here:

slim view:

```
= f.input :company_stages, as: :check_boxes, required: true
```

scss:

```
// simple-form checbox
.checkbox {
    margin-right: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```