# Inline Radio Buttons using simple form and twitter bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I am trying to create a form that displays the radio options inline like this:

O Apple  O Microsoft  O Twitter  O Square

Currently I have this line:

```
<%= f.association :company, as: :radio, label: false %>
```

But my form looks like this:

O Apple
O Microsoft
O Twitter
O Square

I have tried `<div class="form-inline"></div>` around that input and also adding

```
<%= f.association :company, as: :radio, label: false, :item_wrapper_class => 'inline' %>
```

Do I need to change the input to collection?

Comment: possible duplicate of [simple\_form\_for rails radio button inline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985317/simple-form-for-rails-radio-button-inline)

Comment: This is still a work in progress on simplee_form's end. This is the gist that talks about this issue: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/857

The most updated simple_form.rb was updated 2 days ago. Hopefully in a week or two, all updates will be tested and merged back to the master. Then, it will be beautiful again.

Answer (score 0):

with regular rails you can do

```
 <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <%= radio_button_tag "Product Type", "Retail Product or Service", true %>
      Retail Product or Service
    </label>
    <label>
      <%= radio_button_tag "Product Type", "Tax Code", false %>
      Tax Code
    </label>
    <label>
      <%= radio_button_tag "Product Type", "Discount Amount", false %>
      Discount Amount
    </label>
    <label>
      <%= radio_button_tag "Product Type", "Discount Percent", false %>
      Discount Percent
    </label>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this:

```
<label class="checkbox inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> 1
</label>
<label class="checkbox inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2"> 2
</label>
<label class="checkbox inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="option3"> 3
</label>
```

Or this one (tag form only):

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Email">
  <input type="password" class="input-small" placeholder="Password">
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
  </label>
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Comment: try this <%= f.radio_button(:option, "option1") %>
<%= f.label(:option_option1, "option 1") %>
<%= f.radio_button(:option, "option2") %>
<%= f.label(:option_option2, "option 2") %>

Comment: thanks for your answer but im trying to do it using simple_form