# Simple Form Radio Buttons - Display inline

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I'm trying to use Simple Form in my Rails 4 app (with twitter bootstrap).

I have this line in my form. It is a question with a Yes or No answer. I'd like the button to be inline with the label. At the moment, the button appears above the label (so 4 rows, for button, Yes, button, No).

```
 <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :project_image, [[true, '  Yes'] ,[false, '  No']], :first, :last, :inline,  {:class => "create-project", :style=> 'width: 650px' }  %>
```

I should also say that I have tried the solutions posted here: 
    [simple_form_for rails radio button inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985317/simple-form-for-rails-radio-button-inline) and have tried this line:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :project_image, [[true, '  Yes'] ,[false, '  No']], :first, :last, {:inline_label=> true}, {:class => "create-project", :style=> 'width: 650px' }  %>
```

Inspecting that in google shows that there are separate  and  tags.

I have not been able to get this to render inline. Please can you help me understand how to render radio buttons inline the above line.

In response to the suggestion below about adding bootstrap styling to simple form. I tried:

```
     <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :project_image, [[true, '  Yes'] ,[false, '  No']], :first, :last,  {:item_wrapper_class => 'inline'}, {:class => "create-project", :style=> 'width: 650px' }  %>
  </label>
```

The result of the above was to slightly indent the segment but still not rendering inline.
Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [simple\_form\_for rails radio button inline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985317/simple-form-for-rails-radio-button-inline)

Comment: Hi Pavan, no - I tried each of the solutions proposed in that response. The final comments on that page appear to have the same result as me in trying them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **radio-inline** class to your radio buttons.

Refer: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I updated my question to show the way that I tried to use bootstrap styling on the form. It didn't work.

Comment: Try this: <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :price, [[true, ' Yes'] ,[false, ' No']], :first, :last, {:item_wrapper_class => 'inline'}, {:class => "radio-inline create-project" } %>

Answer (score 0):

If the above doesn't work for you, try:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :project_image, [[true, 'Yes'] ,[false, 'No']], :first, :last) do |b| b.label { b.radio_button + b.text } %>
```